# why i can still type this special characters " ` " , " _" and " ^ "

Tags: java, netbeans

why i can still type this special characters " ` " , " _" and " ^ " in jtextfield. with this

```
   private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
   char c = evt.getKeyChar();
   if (!((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'z') ||
          (c == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)||
          (c == KeyEvent.VK_MINUS)||
     (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
     (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
    getToolkit().beep();
    evt.consume();
    }
```

Comment: Because these characters are placed inside `A`- `z` range at Unicode Table (between `Z` and `a` characters we have `[` ``\`` `]` `^` `_` and `\``). Modify your code to specify `A-Z` ranges and `a-z`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the codes of those characters lie between those of 'Z' and 'a' what satisfies your first condition `(c >= 'A') && (c <= 'z')`:

```
DEC HEX BIN      CHR
...
88  58  01011000  X
89  59  01011001  Y
90  5A  01011010  Z
91  5B  01011011  [
92  5C  01011100  \
93  5D  01011101  ]
94  5E  01011110  ^  <---
95  5F  01011111  _  <---
96  60  01100000  `  <---
97  61  01100001  a
98  62  01100010  b
99  63  01100011  c
...
```

Those six characters fill the gap to 32, since the alphabet has only 26 letters, but it's desired to let `a` have code `01100001` (like `A` has `01000001`). This way it was (and still is) easier to read by humans.